# java.net.ServerTimeoutException in VB.Net web service

Tags: android, vb.net, web-services, exception

I make a VB.Net Web Service. And that will be called by Android Emulator from IIS 7.0. Simple method which return sum of 2 digit works fine but when i try to insert record in the database MY SQL SERVER at that time it will generate java.net.ServerTimeoutException. But When I try to run it from Browser at that time it will works fine means it able to insert record in database but from Android Simulator it will give a Exception.

```
package com.BuddiesHub;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class Register extends Activity
{
EditText mobno,password,cnfpassword,secqus,secans;
Button register;    

public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/doRegister";
public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "doRegister"; 
public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/BuddiesHub/Service.asmx";

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=null;
HttpTransportSE httpTransport=null;
PropertyInfo pi=null;
SoapObject request=null;
Object response=null;
//private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";


 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    mobno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtmobno);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
    cnfpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtcnfpassword);
    secqus=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsecqus);
    secans=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsecans);

    register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnregister);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

        //mobno ,name,secqus,secans

        pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("mobno");
        pi.setValue(mobno.getText().toString());
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("name");
        pi.setValue(password.getText().toString());
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("secqus");
        pi.setValue(secqus.getText().toString());
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("secans");
        pi.setValue(secans.getText().toString());
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        //SoapObject response=null;
        // response = null;
        //String result = null;

        try
        {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            response=exception.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    } });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Dear Jeff,  yes i add that permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Simple method which does not deal with database was call successfully and return true value but only method which is deal with database generate the exception.